# cannot stat `freetype-2.4.6/{src,include}':

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, apvpdf

While executing APV Pdf Reader, i executed sh build-native.sh . 
the following error arising... 
cp: cannot stat `freetype-2.4.6/{src,include}': No such file or directory
build-native.sh: 36: ndk-build: not found

Please suggest the way....